Echoing from .jsx into Blade file. ReactJS & Vite
I've got a weird problem where I'm transferring blade.php code into .jsx, and in Blade, PHP's echo {{asset()}} and Blade's @ syntaxed code is referred to a lot.
How would I go about putting it inside .jsx file? What plugins are there to make this easy?
Thank you!

Blade's {{ }} echo statements can be replaced with {} in JSX. For importing U can use import' eg: ``` import '../css/app.css' ``` in JSX components`
